# how to bind a template function

Tags: c++, boost

Hi to all you boost gurus out there!

I want to find a certain element in a vector of strings, ignoring case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/algorithm/string.hpp"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

using std::string;
using std::vector;

bool icmp(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{
    return boost::iequals(str1, str2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back("test");

//  if (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind(&boost::iequals<string,string>, "TEST", _1)) != vec.end()) <-- does not compile
    if (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind(&icmp, "TEST", _1)) != vec.end())
        std::cout << "found" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is working fine so far, but what I would like to know is, if it is possible to get rid of the extra function (icmp()) and invoke iequals (template function) directly (like in the commented line).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the template params and the default locale parameter works on my machine.

```
if (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind(&boost::iequals<string,string>, "TEST", _1, std::locale())) != vec.end())
        std::cout << "found" << std::endl;
```

Compiler is VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is not what you're hoping for, but this appears to be the only fix I can work out 
(with g++ c++03 mode):

```
typedef bool (*fptr)(const std::string&, const std::string&);


if (std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    boost::bind((fptr) &boost::iequals<string,string>, "TEST", _1)
) != vec.end())
```

Comment: Nice! Getting function pointers of overloaded functions is a recurring problem -- it's subtle because it's not obvious at the call site that there's an ambiguity.

Comment: Bad idea.  This does a C-style cast from `bool (*)(const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::locale&)` to `bool (*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)`.  Some template magic is required to deal with that third defaultable parameter.

Comment: On second thought, I don't think template magic can use a default parameter.  So probably the only options are providing the third parameter as @mkaes, or switching to a language-supported C++11 lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Using boost lambda :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::lambda;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    vec.push_back("TEST");
    vec.push_back("test");

    vector<string>::iterator it;

    it = find_if(vec.begin(),vec.end(),_1 == "test");
    cout << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for the editing..I am somehow having trouble in editing..if someone could do it ..that would be great.

Comment: You have lost the call to `boost::iequals`, which is not the same as `operator==`!